# Is the physics of a Quantum Field Theory dependent on the choice of Lagrangian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral

A Quantum Field Theory can be obtained by quantising a Classical Field Theory through to a procedure.  The procedure involves starting with a set of equations of motion that describe a Classical Field Theory, then find a Lagrangian that produces that set of equations of motion, then use that Lagrangian in Quantum Field Theory.

However, we know that different Lagrangians can produce the same equations of motion in Classical Field Theory.  In other words, in Classical Field Theory, as long as two Lagrangians produce the same equations of motion, then we can use either of those.

However, does the Quantum Field Theory depend on the choice of Lagrangian?  In essence, is it possible that two Lagrangians, that produces the same set of equations of motion in Classical Field Theory, lead to different Quantum Field Theories?

Comment: An example would clarify your question. Second quantization is a functor, in case you are thinking about quantization ambiguities.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I've never heard of a functor before (I don't think they teach it in master's level physics).  Do you mean there's no ambiguities, that different Lagrangians lead to the same quantum field theory?

Comment: @CosmasZachos did you mean to say quantization is _not_ a functor?

Comment: Indeed, quantization is aggressively not a functor; only second "quantization"  is such. (A famous Ed Nelson [quote](https://bjp-bg.com/papers/bjp2012_2_107-149.pdf).)

Comment: A functor is a mapping between categories. John Baez has extensively studied categories in physics. Here's some appetizers:  https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/nth_quantization.html https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/categories.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are Lagrangians which have the same equations of motion which do not define the same quantum field theory.

A standard example is the Yang-Mills action with a $\theta$-term:

$S = \int\frac{1}{4} tr[F_A\wedge*F_A] + \theta \int tr[F_A \wedge F_A]$

The second term is a topological invariant, so contributes nothing to the equations of motion.  But the results of path integration do depend non-trivially on $\theta$.

Comment: Why exactly is that true? How can two Lagrangians which give the same reality (equations of motion) possibly give different EOMs in the quantum theory?

Comment: Reality is not governed by equations of motion, but by the path integral and the path integral directly cares about the Lagrangian, not the equations of motion.

Comment: @Sarthak, I leave it to user1504 to expand on this if he wants but the simple mistake that you are making that makes this seem unlikely is that you are equating "equations of motion" to "reality". The universe is described by a quantum theory. Classical equations of motion only give an effective description for (most) physics problems at large scales. So your image of reality is simply wrong.

Comment: @Kvothe good response! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As a corollary, two Lagrangians that look vastly different from each other, producing vastly different classical equations of motion, can actually describe the same physics, if the fields in the two Lagrangians are related to each other by a field redefinition. Field redefinitions, even though they change the action (unobservable), leave the S-matrix (observable) invariant. See also my answer here - https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/491012/133418.

Comment: While true, this is not what the OP asked nor in my opinion that interesting. It is like saying the physics is invariant under changing the symbol you use to write the integral. Or writing it on a different type of paper. The OP is asking about a more interesting case where the two Lagrangians are really inequivalent and produce different physics. As user1504 explains this is also possible.

Comment: Yes, it's right that the field then just becomes an integration variable in the path integral. I mentioned my answer as a corollary because a part of the question asks "Is the physics of a QFT dependent on the choice of L?", and this could be one answer. The reason why this field redefinition redundancy is, I think, not only interesting but also important, is that it shows that Lagrangians are not the most fundamental objects, and that you can e.g. derive physical amplitudes of YM and gravity that describe our universe, without ever knowing what SU(N) or the Ricci scalar is.